# Is it possible to use <ServerSideRender /> to create a "switchable" preview of a Carousel Gutenberg block?

Tags: block-editor

Let's have a block that creates a Carousel using `<InnerBlocks />`:

`edit.js` of the parent component returns something like:

```
    return(
            <div className="carousel">
                <div className="carousel__track">
                        <ul {...innerBlocksProps} className="carousel__list" />
                </div>
            </div>
          )
```

`edit.js` of the child returns something like:

```
   return(
        <li class="slide">
            <figure>
                <img src={url} data-id={id} alt={title} />
                <figcaption>
                   <h5>{caption}</h5>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
      )
```

In the parent `edit.js` I would create a state like; `const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(false)` and when I click a "edit" button the state is set to `false`, when I click a "preview" button the state is set to `true`.

I thought that when the parent state `isPreview` is `true` I could render the Carousel via `<ServerSideRender />`, so I've created a server-side rendered block, let's call it "myblocks/carousel-preview" and I've changed the `edit.js` parent like that:

```
 return(

         {
          !isPreview
          ?
            <div className="carousel">
                <div className="carousel__track">
                        <ul {...innerBlocksProps} className="carousel__list" />
                </div>
            </div>
          )
          :
          <>
            <ServerSideRender
            block="myblocks/carousel-preview"
            attributes={{ /* pass children here?!? */ }}
        />
          </>
```

My main problem is: how can I pass to my `<ServerSideRender />` block the children of my block?

In fact, I thought that the markup of the `<ServerSideRender />` could be something like:

```
    
    <?php 
     function RenderCarouselServerSide($attributes, $content) {
       ob_start();
        ?>
      <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel__track">
          <ul class="carousel__list" />
           <?php foreach($attributes['children'] as $child) :
           $url = $child['url'];
           $id = $child['id'];
           $caption = $child['caption'];
            ?>
           <li class="slide">
            <figure>
                <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <figcaption>
                   <h5>"<?php echo $caption; ?>"</h5>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </li>
         </ul>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

          </div>
      </div>

     <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

But how to pass the children as `$attributes`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My main problem is: how can I pass to my `<ServerSideRender />` block
> the children of my block?

### Well actually, you might not need to use `ServerSideRender`..

If you just wanted to see a preview of the block output coming from the `save()` function, then you could simply use [`getSaveElement()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-blocks/#getSaveElement) to get that output, or the *element* returned by the save function.

Here's an example where I'm using the `useBlockProps` hook introduced in [block API version 2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/18/block-api-version-2/): (**these are all for the main/parent block**)

- Variables I used:

  ```js
  // Used in the 'edit' and 'save' functions.
  const { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;

  // Used in the 'edit' function.
  const { useState } = wp.element;
  const { Button } = wp.components;

  // Used in the preview function.
  const { select } = wp.data;
  const { getSaveElement } = wp.blocks;
  ```
- My edit function:

  ```js
  const edit = ( { clientId } ) => {
      const blockProps = useBlockProps();

      const [ isPreview, setIsPreview ] = useState( false );
      const setPreviewMode = () => setIsPreview( ! isPreview );

      const innerBlocksProps = { /* your code */ };

      return (
          <div { ...blockProps }>
              { isPreview ? (
                  <PreviewBlock
                      clientId={ clientId }
                  />
              ) : (
                  <div className="carousel">
                      <div className="carousel__track">
                          <ul { ...innerBlocksProps } className="carousel__list">
                              <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={ [ 'myblocks/carousel-child' ] } />
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              ) }
              <Button onClick={ setPreviewMode }>{ isPreview ? 'Close Preview' : 'Preview' }</Button>
          </div>
      );
  };
  ```
- My save function:

  ```js
  const save = () => {
      const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( { className: 'carousel' } );

      const innerBlocksProps = { /* your code */ };

      return (
          <div { ...blockProps }>
              <div className="carousel__track">
                  <ul { ...innerBlocksProps } className="carousel__list">
                      <InnerBlocks.Content />
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      );
  };
  ```
- And my preview function/component:

  ```js
  function PreviewBlock( { clientId } ) {
      const { getBlock } = select( 'core/block-editor' );

      const block = getBlock( clientId );

      return getSaveElement( 'myblocks/carousel', block.attributes, block.innerBlocks );
  }
  ```

### If you would rather use `ServerSideRender`, though:

Or if you just need to, then you can use [`getBlocks()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#getBlocks) to retrieve the inner/child blocks, then get the attributes of each of the child block, and include the attributes in the `attributes` property of the `ServerSideRender` element.

So based on my code above, I would only need to make these two changes:

- In the *Variables I used* part, replace the `const { getSaveElement } = wp.blocks;` with `const ServerSideRender = wp.serverSideRender;`.
- Then change the preview function to:

  ```js
  function PreviewBlock( { clientId } ) {
      const { getBlocks } = select( 'core/block-editor' );

      // Get the attributes of the inner/child blocks.
      const blocks = getBlocks( clientId ).map( block => block.attributes );

      return (
          <ServerSideRender
              block="myblocks/carousel-preview"
              attributes={ { children: blocks } }
              httpMethod="POST"
          />
      );
  }
  ```

  Note that the [`httpMethod`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-server-side-render/#httpmethod) (HTTP request method) doesn't have to be set to POST, but POST will allow a bigger attributes object.

And remember, you must register the above `children` attribute *in PHP* (via [`register_block_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/)). E.g.

**Note:** The attribute name doesn't have to be `children`. You can use any other name you like. But be sure the name matches the one used in the preview function above.

```php
register_block_type( 'myblocks/carousel-preview', array(
    'apiVersion'      => 2,
    'render_callback' => 'RenderCarouselServerSide',
    'attributes'      => array(
        'children' => array(
            'type'    => 'array',
            'default' => array(),
        ),
    ),
) );
```

So I hope that helps and you might want to check my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/385968) which sends the block content instead of the inner blocks atrributes, to the server-side renderer.

Comment: Wonderful and complete explanation, thanks!

Comment: The getSaveElement() option almost works for my use case, except <InnerBlocks.Content /> is always automatically wrapped with a <div></div>. So, in the example above, the actual markup in the editor is something like <div className="carousel__track"><ul><div><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></div></ul></div>, which is invalid HTML. Note that it only adds this div in the editor: the actual saved HTML rendered on the front-end does not have a div wrapping the inner content. I've been unable to get rid of this unnecessary div.